# Why the accuracy and loss plot is wavy at the end of training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I was training a word-level sentence generation model and as its training started to reach towards the end of total iterations, the accuracy started to go down and up multiple times and formed a wavy pattern in the history plot. I am unable to understand why is this happening. Is it because of overfitting? Do I need to add some dropout layers to my model?

My model:

```
def rnn_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(uniq_vals, 50, input_length=s_len))
    model.add(SimpleRNN(25, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(SimpleRNN(25))
    model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(uniq_vals, activation='softmax'))
    return model

model = rnn_model()
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.summary()
```

Also I have set the batch_size = 128 and epochs = 150

Accuracy and loss plot: 
[image]

Comment: This is usually caused by the learning rate being too large

Comment: @Mike not likely with the `Adam` optimizer used here.